# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, lucene

While writing on ES through hadoop job ,it freezes with logs as :Caused by: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**: Could not initialize class `org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene`,What might be the reason?

> RemoteTransportException[[Failed to deserialize response of type [org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.node.liveness.LivenessResponse]]]; nested: TransportSerializationException[Failed to deserialize response of type [org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.node.liveness.LivenessResponse]]; nested: NoClassDefFoundError[Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene];
>   Caused by: TransportSerializationException[Failed to deserialize response of type [org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.node.liveness.LivenessResponse]]; nested: NoClassDefFoundError[Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene];
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleResponse(MessageChannelHandler.java:180)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:138)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>       at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
>       at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
>       at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:555)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:107)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
>       at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>       at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was due to the conflict in elasticsearch jar file in class path.My elasticsearch is 2.3.3 which require same version of jar file in my project pom.xml file which was 2.3.2 version elasticsearch before.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i fixed it by deleting log4j and slf4j dependencies.
It seems that Elastic search tries to load log4j logger by default and it creates some conflicts .